# Google Service Account Client Id Authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

I am trying to use google service account for web apps.

Problem.

How I can authorize service account clientid in other domain using admin oauth2.

I am not able to find any doc which refers to this problem.

I can ask an admin to do it manually but I want to avoid manual authorization.

Thanks in advance.